# Java Teste com banco em memória

Tags: java, hibernate

Estou na dúvida quando executar os testes da minha aplicação:

A questão é se existe a possibilidade de fazer o Hibernate criar um banco não físico para realizar os testes em memória, para facilitar e agilizar mais os testes em questão.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voce já ouviu falar de Dbunit?

http://imasters.com.br/banco-de-dados/mysql/automatizando-seus-testes-com-dbunit-mysql/?trace=1519021197&source=single

Ve se te ajuda esse artigo.

Comment: Ajudou bastante!